# Logging web sockets in Azure App Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Framework application deployed on Azure App Services that I am trying to troubleshoot.  I am looking for logs regarding a failed web socket request.  I have application insights which appears to be showing successful web socket connections but not failures.  I have web server logging and the http raw logs do not show either successful or unsuccessful requests.  What is the best way to log and troubleshoot failed web socket connections.

Comment: Have you tried [Enable application logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows)?

Comment: Yes I did enable application logging.  However, it did not contain any useful information regarding web traffic or the failed web socket connection.

Comment: Hello, did you fix it ? i have same problem